# How to use Gorm fuzzy query table name

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use Mysql to fuzzy query the statement of table name:

```sql
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'message_%'
```

is ok, return "message_1".
but, use gorm import `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`:

```golang
...
var result = make([]interface{}, 0)
err := db.DB.Raw("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'message_%'").Scan(&result)
fmt.Println("data:", result, "err:", err)
...

terminal log:
[2022-02-28 18:08:13]  [1.72ms]   SHOW TABLES LIKE 'message_%'  
[1 rows affected or returned ]
data: [<nil>] err: <nil>
```

result is nil, or do I need to use what structure to receive?

Comment: try this `db.DB.Raw("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?", "message_%").Scan(&result)`

Comment: Tried this.result is nil,This has nothing to do with usage

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `information_schema.TABLES`:

```
result := []string{}
err := models.DB.
    Raw(
        "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE ?",
        "message_%",
        "Your Database Name Here",
    ).
    Scan(&result).
    Error
```

And the result will be like:

```
[]string{
    "message_a",
    "message_b",
    "message_c",
    ...
}
```

About `information_schema.TABLES`:

> The TABLES table provides information about tables in databases.
>
> ...
>
> The TABLES table has these columns:
>
> TABLE_CATALOG
>
> The name of the catalog to which the table belongs. This value is always def.
>
> TABLE_SCHEMA
>
> The name of the schema (database) to which the table belongs.
>
> TABLE_NAME
>
> The name of the table.

See: [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table - MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html)

Comment: I tried your way, sql is ok. but result still is empty, it feels like something's wrong with acceptance,
 ` [2022-03-01 10:04:53] [17.10ms] SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'message_%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'live' [1 rows affected or returned ] data: [] err: <nil> `
 The problem is receiving variables.it's not sql problem @Zhwt

Comment: @murloc What does your import look like? It should be `import "gorm.io/gorm"`. And the line `err := db.DB.Raw(...).Scan(...)` should be `err := db.DB.Raw(...).Scan(...).Error`

Comment: Because of the project problem, import  `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`. Using `err := db.DB.Raw(...).Scan(...).Error`. test result is empty.so ask questions